# AWS SNS publish always gets sent with the same message regardless off defined value

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, amazon-sns

I have an `SNS` topic in `eu-west-1` hosted by `AWS`.

If I log into the `aws sns` console and publish manually to mind end point then the notification(s) are sent correctly to the devices with the correct data.

However I have a simple clojure server which uses the `Amazonica` library to handle the aws API calls and regardless of what `message` I send to my `SNS` topic, the notification arrives at the device with the message last used in the `SNS` console.

example:

log into SNS console and send the following:

```
{
"default": "Test data", 
"email": "Test data", 
"sqs": "Test data", 
"lambda": "Test data", 
"http": "Test data", 
"https": "Test data", 
"sms": "Test data", 
"APNS": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"Test data\"} }", 
"APNS_SANDBOX":"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Test data\"}}", 
"APNS_VOIP":"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Test data\"}}", 
"APNS_VOIP_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"Test data\"} }", 
"MACOS":"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Test data\"}}", 
"MACOS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"Test data\"} }", 
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Test data\" } }", 
"ADM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Test data\" } }", 
"BAIDU": "{\"title\":\"Test data\",\"description\":\"Test data\"}", 
"MPNS" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\"><wp:Tile><wp:Count>ENTER COUNT</wp:Count><wp:Title>Test data</wp:Title></wp:Tile></wp:Notification>", 
"WNS" : "<badge version\"1\" value\"23\"/>"
}
```

This is generated using the `generate JSON` feature of the console. This works as expected the notification arrives with the message `Test data`. All is golden.

However if I do the following in clojure:

```
(defn- sns-push [body]
  (sns/publish (env :sns) :topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxsecret"
                          :subject "Dummy Subject"
                          :message "Dummy message"))
```

where `(env :sns)` is set correctly, the notifications get sent but instead of having the message `Dummy message` they are being sent with `Test data` which is the last sent message from the console.

I have no idea what is causing this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Are your queues configured to resend messages that are not deleted from the queue? This is an extremely common configuration for queues. A typical flow is:

1. receive a message
2. process it and save the result
3. if the result was saved, delete the message. 
   otherwise don't delete it from the queue.

If the message is not deleted it will be resent a later time when the queue is read from, allowing it to be eventually processed. This makes the system reliable in the face of queue consumers that could die half way through processing a message (which is *always* the case in any real system). Many refer to this arrangement as "at least once delivery"

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option for that. If that was the case wouldn't it always send the same message? My problem is that the last manual message always gets sent. If I send a message manually it all works as expected.

Comment: This is controlled by the message timeout and retry parameters.